# Need help in TSQL with Charindex

Tags: t-sql, substring, charindex

Need final output as S-05000_Chilling. Right now getting S-05000_Chilling_cle. Apparently, remove everything after last underscore symbol.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(100)
SET @name = 'abc.S-05000_Chilling_cleanup'
select substring(@name,CHARINDEX('.', @name)+1,(len(@name)-CHARINDEX('_', 
reverse(@name))))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@name,CHARINDEX('.', @name)+1, 
    ( (LEN(@name)-CHARINDEX('.', @name))-CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@name) ) ) )
```